How to authenticate Youtube-Data-API v3 with GCC in Streamlit (or any other third party web-framework)
I am using streamlit.io to deploy my app which uses Youtube-data-api v3 to find channel URLS.
default_api_key = "..."  # API key
API_KEY = st.text_input("Enter your YouTube API Key", value=default_api_key, type="password")
API_service_name = 'youtube'
API_version = 'v3'
youtube = build(API_service_name, API_version, developerKey=API_KEY)

I setup the build as shown above and have a few functions calling searches such as the one shown below. That's about all I use the api and api key for.
def get_uploads_playlist_id(api_key, channel_id):
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels'
    params = {
        'part': 'contentDetails',
        'id': channel_id,
        'key': api_key
    }
    
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f'Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}')
        return None
    
    data = response.json()
    
    if 'items' not in data or len(data['items']) == 0:
        print(f'No details found for channel ID: {channel_id}')
        return None
    
    uploads_playlist_id = data['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads']
    return uploads_playlist_id
......

which is then called by for example:
playlist_id = get_uploads_playlist_id(API_KEY, value)

I have created a Client ID for Streamlit and given the correct URIs to my knowledge.

When I run the functions in streamlit locally (haven't deployed it on streamlit community cloud yet) I get the following errors:
Error: 400 - {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_INVALID",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "youtube.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

However everything works locally in my jupyter notebook without the streamlit components. I'm not sure if its an issue with the API key in a python file or with connecting to a third party.
I have tried following some steps in using the credential from above but I'm not sure if the steps were too old or I didn't follow the right steps.
https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/google-authentication-in-a-streamlit-app/43252/6
One of them required a Google ID Token and I'm not sure I have a way to get one? Is it deprecated?
Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.
https://github.com/GeneralCorn/YoutubeTranscript/blob/main/streamlit_app.py
Full code is here for reference (I removed the API Key)

In your sample search code, you're using 'key': api_key,, which is the correct variable that has the API_KEY?, default_api_key, API_KEY, api_key? - If possible, try to deply your code but, only for printing the apikey you're sending. I suspect you're not passing the API_KEY correctly or even, the API_KEY is not included in the request, check closely your code.

@MauricioAriasOlave Hi! Yeah I think I didn't make it clear this is part of a function so it's just the parameter which is in lower case, so I have indeed checked and passed the correct API_KEY.
